# Google Maps iOS Remove Polylines

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is it possible to remove all Polylines without removing other objects?

`[mapView clear];` removes everything including markers

I also tried the following but it didn't work either..

```
for (GMSPolyline __strong *polyline in self.mapView.subviews) {
    polyline = nil;
}
```

Thanks in advance

PS : I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.7.2.7908

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add the polylines you should add them to your own collection. Then when you need to remove them, loop over your own collection and set each polyline's `.map` property to nil (which removes it from the map).

Answer (score 5):

You have to do

> [self.polyline setMap:nil];

, that will remove the line from the map.